# How to update only month in date column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with 30 entries and date column is like following

```
2014-11-01
2014-11-02
2014-11-03
.
.
.
2014-11-30
```

Now i want to write MySQL query to update month from 11 to 10 or you can say from month November to October.

I want to change only month in all these dates from 11 to 10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function for changing the month and [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function for filtering the records. Assuming the table name is `tbl` and the column name is `date`, here's what the query will look like

```
UPDATE `tbl`
SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 11
```